# Xpath exposes text node in dev console but not in python shell

Tags: python, shell, xpath, web-scraping

I'm writing a web scraper that is supposed to be scraping data from rows inside of an html table [here](https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h10/hist/). I'm able to expose all of the text inside of the rows in the table by using this xpath in firebug: `$x('.//*[@class="statistics"]/tbody/tr/th/a/text()')`. Running this shows the full set of all of the text nodes in the table.

I based this xpath on another similar xpath that I had previously used for this site which also returns all of the desired text nodes: `'.//*[@class="productionsEvent"]/text()'`. For some reason, when I try to print the text from the rows of the statistics table inside of the python shell after having simply requested the html, I get an empty list. What might the xpath not be working in the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the `tbody` - it is inserted by the browser and you would not get it when download the page via `urllib2` or `requests`:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring
>>> 
>>> url = "https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h10/hist/"
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> root = fromstring(response.content)
>>> root.xpath('.//*[@class="statistics"]/tbody/tr/th/a/text()')  # with tbody
[]
>>> root.xpath('.//*[@class="statistics"]//tr/th/a/text()')  # without tbody
['Australia', 'Brazil', 'Canada', 'China, P.R.', 'Denmark', 'EMU member countries', 'Greece', 'Hong Kong', 'India', 'Japan', 'Malaysia', 'Mexico', 'New Zealand', 'Norway', 'Singapore', 'South Africa', 'South Korea', '\r\n        ', 'Sri Lanka', 'Sweden', 'Switzerland', 'Taiwan', 'Thailand', 'United Kingdom', 'Venezuela']
```